# Get column name in data frame if value is between values

Tags: pandas, range, match, multiple-columns, between

I have a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

random_number_gen = np.random.default_rng()
df = pd.DataFrame(random_number_gen.integers(-5, 5, size=(1, 13)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLM'))
```

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 4 | -4 | -1 | 3 | -5 | -3 | 0 | -4 | -1 | 3 | 2 |

I would like to obtain the names of the columns where a value falls between -1 and 1. I tried this and others:

```
df.columns[(( -1<= df.any()) & (df.any() <=1)).iloc[0]]
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: do you always have a single row?

Comment: yes, I want to use the result as a mask on another dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single row:

```
df.columns[df.iloc[0].between(-1,1)]

# or
df.columns[df.squeeze().between(-1,1)]
```

If you can have multiple rows:

```
df.columns[(df.ge(-1)&df.le(1)).any()]
```

Example output:

```
Index(['E', 'G', 'J'], dtype='object')
```

Used input:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M
0  3 -3 -4 -3 -1  3 -1 -5 -2  1  3  2  4
```